# Does change of tcp_keepidle or any of the tcp parameters require a reboot(AIX)?

Tags: networking, tcp, aix, parameters

`AIX 5.3`
`oslevel -r`
`5300-12`

We require to change the `tcp_keepidle` value using :

`no -o <tcp_parameter>= <tcp _value>`

Does this change require a reboot or network services restart to take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not require reboot. But it only affects future connections. For more details try either man pages for "no" or "no -L"